# What is the best way to integrate sending dynamic emails from different senders from a Vue web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, smtp, email

I am making a web application like gumtree. I am currently using AWS for the backend so would like to avoid making a node express server if possible. Everything I have found so far is about transactional emails, promotional emails, contact forms from just one verified sender or domain which is not what I am looking to do. I want to be able to send dynamic emails, i.e the sender would be a user of the web app and the receiver would be a user of the web app. Exactly like the gumtree e-mailing feature.[gumtree email example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hitzK.png)

Comment: **i.e the sender would be a user of the web app and the receiver would be a user of the web app.** I'm sorry, can it be more clearer? you mean like an `invitational email` ?

Comment: No I mean, in context if you wanted to buy an item from a seller, you would email the seller from the web app. Both the buyer and seller are authenticated users of the web app. Hope this helps.

Comment: thx, much clearer. so you wanted communication between both via email function. I would only say that `mailing function` can be only done securely via server/express (just Vue and Axios isn't enough) as usually server will send your email content along with `username` with its domain on behalf of you, to the recipient, and update your AWS backend for records as well. Hope helps

Comment: Thanks I'll have to stick with express then.